# Opening a PDF uploaded file in a new tab in Internet Explorer in using html

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, browser

This is the code I added in my Index file on my site:

[Full PDF Catering Menu](http://hmfcatering.com/cateringmenu.pdf)

Instead of opening the file in the internet browser, it only gives me the option to download the file.

Can any one help me solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 (file opens inside the browser).

Which version of IE does not work? Maybe you don't have any PDF Viewer plugin installed?